# Как применять unit test к ASP.NET MVC Database First

Tags: c#, asp.net, юнит-тесты, ado.net

В контроллере есть метод добавления новой записи в базу

```
  public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Cat")] Category category) //
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Categories.Add(category);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("Добавление прошло успешно!");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(category);
    }
```

Как правильно выполнить юнит тест на проверку добавления. Все примеры что я искал основаны на code first, и категорически отличаются от моего контроллера.

Comment: сформулируйте, что вы хотите проверить. что контроллер будет вызван? что контроллер что-то вызовет? что модель будет сохранена?

Comment: Что контроллер что-либо вызовет и сохранит.

Comment: это не юнит-тест.